# Shva Nah and Nach

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Our son is in first grade and is almost seven. His yeshiva called us to tell us that he is getting some shva nah's and some shva nach's mixed up. I also noticed this. I am trying to clarify the following. If I am not mistaken the shva in the following words are shva nah's, even though they are not the first letter in the word. I looked in his kriah neimah sefer from last year to try to find a klal that explains this. I was not able to find.

בִּרְקִיעַ
לִמְאוֹרֹת 
הַמְּאֹרֹת 
הַגְּדֹלִים

הַיְאֹר 
וַיְהִי
הַדְּבָרִים

Is it because the letter before the shva is a prefix? Is there a klal for this?